# Issue after upgrade eXist 2.2 to 4.5 with specific queries

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery, exist-db

So in my previous post I covered many things about indexing that I learned from upgrading from eXist-db 2.2 to 4.5.

Now I have this confusing issue which I can easily show in screens that I need someone to comment on to help me understand. I can create a fix to modify every XML in the DB, but that seems ... well, wrong.

I ported over a large database and this includes a large customer database. Customer subscriptions are stored as XML files. I exported the old DB and imported all this to the new DB.

Sample data in the old database through oXygen looks like this:

[image]

Without touching anything else, if I use oXygen to view the XML file in the new DB I see this (I am cutting out a bunch of content that is private) but nothing is really wrong, just no pretty print as they say:

[image]

So now, I do a simple query through this entire collection like this:

```
xquery version "3.0";
let $colcust := '/db/EIDO/data/Customers'
let $docnum := 'A01'
return count(collection($colcust)/customer/portal/specialty/document[@docnum = $docnum])
```

I get 692 which is exactly correct. There are 692 occurrences of this. A perfect result.

Now, I would like to do some indexing to improve this. So I create this:

```
<collection xmlns="http://exist-db.org/collection-config/1.0">
    <index>
        <range>
            <create qname="user_id" type="xs:string"/>
            <create qname="territory" type="xs:string"/>
            <create qname="@name" type="xs:string"/>
            <create qname="@docnum" type="xs:string"/>
            <create qname="@subscribed" type="xs:string"/>
            <create qname="lang" type="xs:string"/> 
            <create qname="title" type="xs:string"/>
            <create qname="type" type="xs:string"/>
        </range>
    </index>
</collection>
```

I place it in /system/config in the proper place.
And I run the exact same query ... I get "0" not 692 but 0 hits.

OK, so I think something is wrong and I open one of the actual XML files and I see all linefeeds stripped, no pretty print. So I use oXygen to pretty print it so I can examine the paths to make sure I didn;t do something wrong. I actually hit "save" without changing anything. I run the query again and oops! I get "1" hit, the file I just pretty printed. I open another one and I pretty print the XML and save, and I get 2. In disbelief I try again and get 3 and then 4.

I remove the collection.conf and I run and I still get 692.
I put it back in and I now get 4.

I went back to the ZIP created for the backup and cracked it open and sure enough, all the files have their linefeeds stripped. So this is exactly what was imported.

So, the question is ... why does the collection.conf I list above change the result of the simple query I posted? Or maybe why does an XML stored in the DB with no pretty print seem to break indexing?

I could probably just create an xQuery that will apply identity XSL to all XMLs but that seems like an awful hack to me. Is this a known behavior? If so is there any backup/restore settings that does not do this or?

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question on this one. Apparently something was broken in the indexing in some way. I took note of the indexing time when running a re-index and it seemed awful fast. Even though the monex app showed the indexes in place. I cut out everything in the collection.xconf except @docnum and reindexed and it took much longer. The search yielded the correct result.

Then I restored the remainder of the collection.xconf and reindexed and again it took much longer and delivered the correct result. The documents I edited were being reindexed hence those were being hit.

Comment: I had a similar problem - as I understand it, re-indexing is only automatic in eXide. Otherwise, one has to manually force reindexing. See @joewiz ' response here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299588/exist-db-basic-lucene-query-returns-empty-sequence/53300677#53300677